# Finding CRLF in string

Tags: java

I have a file and I want to read in the string on each line. If the line does not end in CRLF (\r\n), I want to to print something. I made this file by redirecting output from print commands similar to the following.

```
System.out.println("Test\r\n");
```

But when I read this line in from the file using buffered reader, it doesn't seem like it catches the CRLF.

I use the following to detect the crlf (where inputline is the line that has been read in).

```
if(inputline.indexOf("\r\n")<0)
```

It never detects the \r\n. How can I remedy this? Is this an issue with buffered reader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> readLine
>
> public String readLine()
>                   throws IOException
>
> Read a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.
>
> Returns:
>
> A String containing the contents of the line, **not including any line-termination characters**, or null if the end of the stream has been reached

from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Thus you may need to write some of your own code (or take this, borrowed from http://www.coderanch.com/t/276442//java/Reading-file-byte-array)

```
private byte[] toByteArray(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{  
    int length = (int) file.length();  
    byte[] array = new byte[length];  
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);  
    int offset = 0;  
    while (offset < length) {  
        offset += in.read(array, offset, (length - offset));  
    }  
    in.close();  
    return array;  
    }
```

This will give you all the bytes - nothing stripped. Knock yourself out looking for `\r\n`...

Comment: Thanks! What would be better to use instead?

Comment: What do you expect the line to end in, if not CR/LF? What are you really trying to do here? You could read raw bytes...

Comment: I would like to print a statement if there is no CRLF. How could I read the read raw bytes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use java.util.Scanner which knows how to find lines in a file (or text)

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("filename"));
while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
}
```